# How to divide group in R

Tags: r, grouping

If I have a series like this:

```
s={9, 4, 6, 5, 3, 10, 5, 3, 5)}
```

I want to divide the group by the number 5

at the end , it has to be

```
s1={9, 4, 6, 5}    
s2={5, 3, 10, 5}    
s3={5, 3, 5}
```

I have already tried

```
cut(ss,ss==5)
```

what am i supposed to do?

what function that i can use?

Comment: Surely you at least know how to post a proper vector in R....

Comment: @Rorita_Tai Suppose your vector is `s1 <- c(5,1,4,5,5,7,9,5,5)`, can you tell us the groupings for this vector?

Comment: thank you guys, that's exactly the answer i want!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an approach to generate a list containing the three vectors:

```
# the original vector
s <- c(9, 4, 6, 5, 3, 10, 5, 3, 5) 

# an index vector
idx <- unique(c(1, which(s == 5), length(s)))

# create a list
mylist <- lapply(seq(length(idx) - 1), function(i) s[idx[i]:idx[i+1]])

mylist
# [[1]]
# [1] 9 4 6 5

# [[2]]
# [1]  5  3 10  5

# [[3]]
# [1] 5 3 5
```

You can access the list elements with `[[`, e.g., `mylist[[1]]` for the first vector.